# fastest way of matching an NSStrings to words in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an NSArray of over 2000 words coupled with an equally long list of scores. I want to iterate over each word in a sentence/text file that a user inputs and for each word get the score for each word that exists in my list. Below is the way I am currently doing this, however I doubt this is the fastest way. My question is if there is a faster way of doing what I am trying to accomplish?

```
  [sentence enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [sentence length])
                               options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized
                            usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){
                                NSUInteger index=[wordArray indexOfObject:substring];
                                if (index!=NSNotFound) {
                                    double score=scoreArray[index];
                                    do something with the score
                                        }
                            }];
```

Comment: if order is not important, use `NSSet`, otherwise use `NSOrderedSet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two thousand is a small-ish sized array.  Before you go to far, [read Knuth's view about premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).  Put effort into speeding it up after you see a manifest problem.  If you get to that point, this does sound like a good application for NSMutableDictionary.  It can have 2k keys which are words, do a (NSSet-like) lookup, and keep an associated value (the "score" in your app).

So for each word in the file:

```
NSNumber *score = self.dictionary[word];
if (score) {
    NSNumber *newScore = // whatever
    self.dictionary[word] = newScore;
}
```

If order matters, you can always sort after-the-fact.